# Use Firebug's Net panel Data for output?

Tags: ajax, firebug

Is there any way to use the information that is seen in the Net Panel section of `firebug`? If Firebug/FF can get that data, why can't we use that to output info to our DOM?
My app uses a modified version of this [AJAX Solr framework](http://evolvingweb.github.io/ajax-solr/examples/reuters/index.9.html). Try entering **York"**  as a serch term (note the one set of quotes).

This will give an error. Check out the difference between the error in Console vs what is under the `GET` error message in the Net panel.

Comment: Obviously this is a bug in the AJAX Solr framework, because the user should get a valid result for that query or at least an understandable error message. The framework should offer you as developer a way to access the response body. I saw it's using jQuery to make the requests, which offers you an [error handler](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/).

Comment: That is the error function that I use but that gives a generic error message which is even less helpful for long and/or complex search inputs. How does Firebug capture that and display it in the Net panel when jquery can't...or doesn't?

Comment: Firebug uses [internal Firefox APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpActivityObserver) to [get all the information](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/content/firebug/net/httpActivityObserver.js) around network requests. These APIs are not exposed to websites, though, so you won't be able to use them via jQuery, unfortunately.